# What's the proper way to let the user enter the name of an object of a class in c++?

Tags: c++

There was a similar question to this for JAVA, but haven't found much help for  c++

I have a class

```
class Animal
{ 
.......
};
```

I want the user to be able to enter the object name. Something like

```
string animalName;
cout <<" Enter name of animal" << endl;
cin >> animalName;
```

Then use the animalName to create an object.

I know I can't use

```
Animal animalName;
```

Because it will call the object "animalName" and not what the user entered.

I also tried

```
 Animal (animalName);
```

from some posts I've read but I seem to be having issues with that..

What's the proper way to do that?

Comment: `int animalName;` cannot be a string :(

Comment: What is "object name"? If it means the name of class, I guess it should be difficult.

Comment: No, you have to deal yourself with input : use a switch case, if else if else..., map or what you want to map input user to effective class

Comment: Specifically: C++ does not have reflection, so you can't automatically map an arbitrary string to a corresponding class type or instance. (probably the closest thing is `typeid`/`name`, but those aren't specified by the Standard, so it's nonportable and really best avoided)

Comment: If you use a `std::map`, you can store objects by a string, but you cannot dynamically name a variable.

Comment: C++ is just not that kind of girl. A compiled program has no concept of a variable name.

Comment: C++ is not Java, read about factory class or factory method pattern

Comment: @rose What, exactly, are you trying to achieve? If you want your animal to have a name that the user chooses, then that would (probably) be a member of the `Animal` class. The names of variables are a different thing entirely, and not something the user will ever see.

Comment: @Slava OP wants the user input to be the *variable name*, not the class type.

Comment: Having an object name as userdefined(which is not possible) or some designer defined does not really matter in the end, No one is going to see it, If you want an user defined name to Animal, make it a member variable and construct Animal with that name.

Comment: Do you want to change the *name of the variable*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use something like that :

```
std::map<int, Animal> animals;

int animalName;
cout <<" Enter name of animal" << endl;
cin >> animalName;

animals.emplace(animalName, Animal{}); // If c++11
// If before c++11 :
// animals.insert(std::make_pair(animalName, Animal{}));
// Or, but less efficiente (thanks to Jarod42)
// animals[animalName] = Animal{};
```

Also, if you want really use a name (and according to comments) you can improve like that :

```
std::map<std::string, Animal> animals;

std::string animalName;
cout <<" Enter name of animal" << endl;
cin >> animalName;

animals.emplace(animalName, Animal{}); // If c++11
// If before c++11 :
// animals.insert(std::make_pair(animalName, Animal{}));
// Or, but less efficiente (thanks to Jarod42)
// animals[animalName] = Animal{};
```

Comment: Yes, but why `int`? I would say either change the instruction to *"Enter Id of animal"*, or the type to `string`.

Comment: It's not my choice, it's her. I just reuse what she use. I agree with you, for animal name I prefer use std::string, but it's not my code ;)

Comment: `animals[animalName] = Animal;` won't compile.

Comment: thank you!! Yes it was supposed to be string.. My mistake

Comment: @songyuanyao be creative, initiate animals as you want ;)

Comment: BTW, Here `animals[animalName] = Animal{};` may simply be replaced by `animals[animalName];`.

Comment: @Jarod42 Yes it may. I prefer the explicit form, which (in my opinion) is more clear of what happens, and also, always in my opinion, doesn't look like an instruction without side effect. Also, it lets the opportunities to extends example with no default constructor

Comment: `emplace` or `insert` would be even more explicit, avoid useless assignation and manage class without default constructor (as `operator []` requires it anyway).